# Framing 16" on center and it doesn't divide evenly

Tags: framing

100% Grade A noob here - learning framing - go easy on me :)

I was looking at framing a shed. I see you can get 10 foot 2x4s.
If I put joists every 16" on center, it doesn't divide evenly - see the first pic.

My question is - what is the typical convention?

- Frame it like this?
- Or shorten the frame to finish at the 8th joist

What do framers typically do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Framers are typically instructed on the size to make things. Make the dimension judgements based on your site constraints and aesthetic goals.

Comment: If you're going to elevate the shed on legs, the typical detail is to notch the posts to transfer load in bearing.

Comment: Did you mean to indicate that you're planning on doing the floor joists with 2x4?  If your description of finding 2x4 come in 10' lengths, then that will be woefully under-supported.  Also, as Cheery said in their answer, space the joists to match your flooring spacing for easier construction.

Comment: 16 or 24 inch spacing is mainly for 4x8 sheets.  You want a stud at every four foot.  There is nothing saying you cannot add an extra stud/joist if the spacing leaves an 18 or 20 inch opening at one end.

Comment: You're gonna need 3 sheets of plywood for this anyway, so I'd center the joists.

Comment: Are you really framing a floor with 2x4s? That’ll be bouncy/saggy, even for a shed. Add more posts and a central beam if you really have to have 2x4s.

Comment: I've got the bottom at 2x6. Sorry I said 2x4 it was meant to be 2x6.
Notched posts - does that mean the rim joist sits on top of the grooved post? I guess a 6x6.
What does center the joists mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Framers would in most cases follow your first picture. They would be following plans. When doing a DIY project, you have the choice of sizing based on materials needed, You might decide to shorten the length to save on a sheet of plywood.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the 8*4 plywood sheet to end right at the center of the 3rd joist. Once you have that, mark 16" off center to either side. Forget about the even spacing.